# Can one still be infected by just replying an email nowadays?

Tags: email, gmail, internet-security

[Here](http://www.betterwhois.com/domainhijacking.htm)—in item number 5 in the list—is a recommendation not to reply to anonymous emails because of the possibility of being infected. I know that once upon a time that was possible [because of JavaScript](http://www.howtogeek.com/135546/htg-explains-why-you-cant-get-infected-just-by-opening-an-email-and-when-you-can/). But now, is it still an issue? Especially for higher security email services such as Gmail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The risk in replying to domain registration emails comes from edge risks from social engineering hijacking and not actually being “infected.”

> Here—in item number 5 in the list—is a recommendation not to reply to
>   anonymous emails because of the possibility of being infected.

Looking at [item number 5 on the page you are linking to](http://www.betterwhois.com/domainhijacking.htm) shows that none of that has anything to do with basic end-user email infections:

> **5. Do not reply (or click on any links) in any domain related e-mail correspondence you do not recognize.** Also be careful not to reply to
>   any 'official looking' renewal notices you receive in the mail from
>   companies you do not recognize. Domain hijackers and unscrupulous
>   registrars have been known to submit mass amounts of transfers hoping
>   that a small percentage of confused registrants will accidentally
>   confirm the transfers. When in doubt, contact your original registrar
>   to verify any suspicious messages.

After reading that, it’s pretty clear the advice is about how to avoid fraudulent domain name registration transfers and related domain registrar changes. Meaning if you do get some email notification from your real domain registrar that “your action is needed” to complete a process, don’t act on it at all. Or else you run the risk of kicking off a process where someone—who is not you—might be able to steal your domain name right out from under you.

That said, those instructions seem quite archaic. The page has a copyright date of 2009 but even back then it was not that “magically” easy to steal a domain registration that way.

The reality is domain registration changes nowadays require a few more checks and balances—and lots more “social engineering” skills (aka: being a complete con artist)—and cannot be simply affected by triggering one simple email. So while this advice is somewhat sound—it’s always good to ignore unwanted emails—it’s also a tad paranoid.

#### Regarding the core question about replying to emails—in general—being an infection risk.

> I know that once upon a time that was possible because of JavaScript.
>   But now, is it still an issue? Especially for higher security email
>   services such as Gmail.

The chances of you getting infected by replying to an email is fairly low to none since *replying* has *never* been a vector. The only email infection risk that once existed came from *looking* at—or *opening*—an email since if the email had HTML content, there *was* a risk that HTML *could* contain embedded malicious JavaScript.

This was once a risk in some email browsers/programs that did not properly filter/deactivate JavaScript from emails such as—drumroll—Microsoft Outlook which treated HTML email as if they were just HTML web pages. The simple act of treating an HTML email as if it were an HTML web page opened a fairly wide door to infections simply by looking at an email.

So you are 100% correct to think that nowadays there are more protections in place. And the main “protection” in place in that any *truly competent* modern email browser/program is to simply *not* run JavaScript at all when displaying HTML email content. As explained on this page on [“The Do’s and Don’ts of Email HTML”](http://help.verticalresponse.com/how-to/tutorial/the_dos_and_donts_of_email_html/):

> Don’t use Javascript. It will be ignored or even treated as a security
>   risk. Once someone receives a security notice about one of your
>   emails, they’ll be unlikely to ever open another one.

The only edge risk I can think of is if you were somehow using an outdated, browser-based email client that did not actively filter JavaScript in HTML emails. In that case, the browser-based email program would just display the HTML email within a web browser. Which would—of course—just display the HTML content of the email as if it were a pure web browser HTML page… JavaScript and all. But like I said, that is *strictly* an edge risk nowadays, but one you should be aware of if you somehow come across—and need to use—a browser-based email program.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it is often advised to delete spam emails without opening them is to limit the feedback provided to the spammers.

Ideally we want it to be impossible for the spammers to tell the difference between an email that was caught by a spam filter and an email that got past the spam filter but was recognized as spam by the user.

If the spammers can tell the difference between the two scenarios, they can automate adjustments to their spam mails aimed at getting past spam filters.

Replying to an email, clicking on a link in an email, or loading external files in order to render it all provides feedback to spammers, which we want to avoid.

In some contexts the advice is given without explaining the reason behind it, and sometimes with the implied reason, that not following the advice will cause your computer to get infected by a virus. Though vulnerabilities have existed, which would make such infections possible, that was never the primary reason for the advice.

As pointed out in the [answer by @Giacomo1968](https://superuser.com/a/892623/167207), the page you link to provide yet another reason to not reply or click on any links. That reason is targeted at specific workflows regarding domain management. However it may apply to other workflows and generally any spam mail may be part of a social engineering attack. Sometimes those social engineering attacks can be so convoluted that even the most security aware users may find the email suspicious, but be completely incapable of explaining how it could be useful as part of a social engineering attack.

Whether all three reasons or only one of the three applies to a specific email, the advice remains the same. And some users are quite satisfied only remembering the advice and not the reasoning behind it.